# Linear transformation and differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

"In the vector space $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of smooth, real functions we consider the subspace W is spanned by the linearly independent set $a=(t,e^t,e^{-t})$

Consider the transformation $f: W \rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ given by: $f(x(t)) = x^n(t)-x'(t)$

**Find the image of f by the function $\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+t$**

I am not sure how to approach this. I'm confused by the raise to ^n and what it means.

What is some good advice which can help understanding the question?

Comment: As long it is not clear what $x^{n}(t)$ means it will remain difficult to answer your problem. I guess that it means the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative because the $n^{\text{th}}$ power does not seem to lead to a simple result.

Comment: What is $W$ in your question ?

Comment: Ah, very sorry I forgot to add the first information. Please see the first paragraph @MrYouMath

Comment: I'd say that `^n` stands for $n$-th derivative.